# Ember - how to make a parent component trigger behaviour on its child components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created a generic form component called **form-field-input**, which validates the user input on focus out.

**form-field-input.hbs**

```html
<label>{{label}}</label>
{{input 
 placeholder=label 
 value=value 
 focus-out='validate'  
 required=required 
 type=type
}}
<p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

**form-field-input.js**

```js
actions: {
  validate: function() {
    var type = this.get('type');
    this.set('checked', true);
    if (this.get('required')) {
      if (this.get('value') === '') {
        this.set('invalid', true);
        this.set('valid', false);
        this.set('errorMessage', 'This field cannot be blank');
        return
      }
    }
    if (type === 'Email') {
      this.send('validateEmail');
    }
    ...
  },
}
```

If I place several instances of the component into a form (as shown below), the validation works perfectly when the user focuses out of each input.

```html
<form {{action "login" on="submit"}}>
    {{form-field-input label='Email' value=email type='Email' required=true }} 
    {{form-field-input label='Password' value=password type='Password' required=true}} 
    {{input type="submit" value="Log In"}}
</form>
```

I would like to validate each **form-field-input** component when the user clicks submit as well (so clicking submit without filling any fields would trigger the validation error message on each required form field component).

Is this achievable, or do I need to put the validation code into the parent component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A form consist of some different input fields. Every input fields are related with one or more attributes of a data (say model). A form reflects that model. A validation of a model needs to have an integrity. So you should check not only fields of that model, but the model's itself as a whole.

For example, think that a person object has two field: birth year and birth country. You may want to check if that country exists at that year. (There was no country with name Kazakhistan at year 1970.) You cannot achieve validating this by only validating single fields.

As a result, in my opinion, you should have validations at parent components that represent a meaningful model. So you should pass the validation data to the child components.

Sample pseudo code:

```
{{#form-component validationRules=validationRules as |f|}}
   {{f.date-input value=(readonly birthDate) propertyName='birthDate'}}
   {{f.text-input value=(readonly birthCountry) propertyName='birthCountry'}}
{{/form-component}}
```

Comment: That answer follows the "Data down, Actions up" Ember mantra, which is a good practice to follow in Ember.